# ServiceStack OpenID Identity Server

Tags: servicestack, openid, dotnetopenauth, openid-provider

We are developing a suite of [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) based sites and would like to share user credentials between them.

From reading around, I THINK what we need, is for one of the sites to act as an OpenID Identity server, with both it and the other sites logging into its OpenID realm (Excuse me if the lingo is incorrect!).

I understand that ServiceStack, with [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/), can authenticate against custom OpenID realms, and it seems that DotNetOpenAuth can also act as an OpenID provider, which could be what we need, but I haven't yet found any examples of how to put the two together.

Am I on the right track, and if so, does anyone have an example of this?

Many thanks.

**Update:**

Further reading suggests [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) could be the solution, but I suspect hosted outside of ServiceStack?

Comment: OpenID 2.0 is deprecated.  You should probably be looking for  implementation of OpenID Connect.